# Google material design icons not loading in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-material-icons

Google Chrome is unable to render [Google Material Icons.](https://design.google.com/icons/)

Here's a snapshot of how the material icons website looks:

[image: Material icons on Google Chrome]

Version is **42.0.2311.90 (64-bit)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out Google has stopped material design icons support for Google Chrome version 42.0.2311.90 and equivalent.

The material icons are working fine after upgrading to 49.x.